# Postgres: Group by a LIKE expression?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.4. I have the following query:

```
select sum(items) as items, sum(cost) as cost, 
       presentation_code, processing_date as date 
  from vw_presentation_summary 
  where presentation_code LIKE '011%' OR presentation_code LIKE '012%' 
  GROUP BY date, presentation_code;
```

This gives me results like this:

```
 items |       cost       | presentation_code |    date
-------+------------------+-------------------+------------
  8243 |        273445.45 | 0212000AAAAACAC   | 2014-03-01
   366 |         10511.99 | 0212000AABBABAB   | 2013-05-01
   461 |          9232.04 | 0212000AABBADAD   | 2014-02-01
```

But is there any way I can group all the results for `011%` together, and all the results for `012%` together?

Comment: I think I need an aggregate function? But not sure how to Google this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to replace "presentation_code" in the select and group by elements with an expression such as:

```
substr(presentation_code,1,3)
```

Comment: thanks - any idea whether this is likely to be more efficient than other approaches suggested here?

Comment: It might be worth benchmarking them -- probably Left() is slightly more CPU efficient than SubStr(), but it's difficult to guess as it might be implemented as a SubStr(). For large data sets the cost of the sort associated with the GROUP BY would predominate.

Comment: If it's important to you to query against the first three characters of that column then you might try indexing on Left(presentation_code,3) and then using "where Left(presentation_code,3) in ('011','012')"

Answer (score 2):

You can group by any expression in postgres, the problem here is that `presentation_code` needs to be an aggregate of some kind or truncated in a way that it can be grouped on. Here is one example:

```
select sum(items) as items, sum(cost) as cost, 
       CASE WHEN presentation_code LIKE '011%' THEN '011'
            WHEN presentation_code LIKE '012%' THEN '012'
       END AS code,
       processing_date as date 
  from vw_presentation_summary 
  where presentation_code LIKE '011%' OR presentation_code LIKE '012%' 
  GROUP BY date, code;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
group by left(presentation_code, 2)
```